# In valued fields (of rank > 1), is the p-adic completion of the algebraic closure still algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a valued field and assume its valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is $p$-adically separated.  If we assume further that $K$ is algebraically closed and we take the $p$-adic completion, is the result algebraically closed?

I know many places where this is asserted for rank 1 valuations, and as far as I can tell the "usual" proof works basically the same way in the more general case.  For example, I think the proof in these notes by Brian Conrad http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248APage/handouts/algclosurecomp.pdf works the same, as long as you replace the absolute values by valuations and replace things like $\frac{1}{j}$ with something like $v(p^j)$.  I've looked briefly through Bourbaki's *Commutative Algebra* and Zariski-Samuel's book and haven't seen this fact; those references seem so comprehensive I'm nervous that the result is not true and I am missing something.

Thanks very much for any help!  Best would be a reference I can use, but I'd also be happy with someone reassuring me this result I want is correct.  I'd also be happy to know if there is a more natural way to phrase it than how I've phrased it (in terms of a valuation ring being $p$-adically separated).

---

Here are a few additional comments.  I think I have written up a proof of algebraic closedness, but I would still be reassured if someone can tell me this is a well-known fact.

Thanks @Lubin for your comment!  I don't know what the most standard example of a valuation ring of rank > 1 is.  The example I feel like I understand the best is the following.  Let $k$ be a perfect valued field of characteristic $p$ and rank 1.  (I picture something like $k = \mathbb{F}_p((t^{1/p^{\infty}}))$ with the $t$-adic valuation.)  Then take the $p$-typical Witt vectors $W(k)$ and let $K = W(k)[1/p]$.  I believe then you can put a rank 2 valuation on this field with value group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$ with the lexicographic ordering, where the first entry corresponds to the $p$-adic valuation and where the second entry corresponds to the $t$-adic valuation.  The corresponding valuation ring is similar to an example in Remark 4.6 from these notes from a course taught by Bhargav Bhatt [www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/perfectoid2.pdf](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/perfectoid2.pdf) It includes elements like $p(1/[t])$ and $[t]$ but not $1/[t]$.  I'm afraid I don't have an algebraically closed example if that's what you wanted... the best I could say would be take the algebraic closure of the example I just gave.

Because I said the valuation ring was $p$-adically separated, I'm pretty sure the $p$-adic completion is the same as the "usual" completion of a valued field...  Explicitly I'd want the completion to consist of $p$-adic Cauchy sequences $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$, where for every $j > 0$, there exists an $N > 0$ such that if $n_1, n_2 > N$, we have $x_{n_1} - x_{n_2} \in p^j \mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: It’s been a while since I’ve thought about valuations of rank $>1$. Can you give us an example of one such field? And your mention of “$p$-adic completion” in this context disquiets me somewhat. Could you say exactly what that means (say, in opposition to completion with respect to the already-existing topological or uniform structure)?

Comment: Thanks for your further explanation. As you can see from my questions, I’m not likely to have the technical skills to help you at all. But I may ask for further clarification(s).

Comment: But do you really want the $p$-adic topology? Seems to me that the sequence $\{t^n\}$ is not $p$-adically convergent. Or do you care about that?

Comment: @Lubin I'm definitely not an expert on these rings, but my impression is that in my example, $\{ [t^n] \}$ should not be considered a Cauchy sequence for the valuation I described.  I also don't think the valuation ring I described is $[t]$-adically separated... for example, I think $p$ is divisible by $[t]^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, this only confirms that I’m totally confused, and unfortunately have nothing to contribute to the subject. Good luck, your question is definitely interesting.